# How to maximize every `window.open` call in Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, electron, window.open, maximize-window

I've known that we could use the following code to maximize the main window:

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({...})

mainWindow.maximize()
```

But what about the `window.open` calls from within the main window? How to maximize them as well?

Using `new BrowserWindow({ fullscreen: true })` is not an option, since that would cause the opened windows to have no title bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to intercept the window creation and maximize them there (this will also affect windows opened from clicking on hyperlinks with `target="_blank"`)

Assuming you're on Electron 12 or higher:

```js
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-create-window', win => win.maximize())
```

As for the second part of the question in your comment, you'll want to hide the window before it's ready to show:

```js
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(() => ({
  action: 'allow',
  overrideBrowserWindowOptions: { show: false },
}))

mainWindow.webContents.on('did-create-window', win =>
  win.once('ready-to-show', () => win.maximize()),
)
```